# Splitting chinese document into sentences

Tags: nlp, tokenize, stanford-nlp, sentence

I have to split Chinese text into multiple sentences. I tried the Stanford DocumentPreProcessor. It worked quite well for English but not for Chinese.

Please can you let me know any good sentence splitters for Chinese preferably in Java or Python.

Comment: Is your text segmented or unsegmented?

Comment: It is unsegmented. I did the sentence splitting after that i used the stanford segmenter. Do i have to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Using some regex tricks in Python (c.f. a modified regex of Section 2.3 of http://aclweb.org/anthology/Y/Y11/Y11-1038.pdf):

```
import re

paragraph = u'\u70ed\u5e26\u98ce\u66b4\u5c1a\u5854\u5c14\u662f2001\u5e74\u5927\u897f\u6d0b\u98d3\u98ce\u5b63\u7684\u4e00\u573a\u57288\u6708\u7a7f\u8d8a\u4e86\u52a0\u52d2\u6bd4\u6d77\u7684\u5317\u5927\u897f\u6d0b\u70ed\u5e26\u6c14\u65cb\u3002\u5c1a\u5854\u5c14\u4e8e8\u670814\u65e5\u7531\u70ed\u5e26\u5927\u897f\u6d0b\u7684\u4e00\u80a1\u4e1c\u98ce\u6ce2\u53d1\u5c55\u800c\u6210\uff0c\u5176\u5b58\u5728\u7684\u5927\u90e8\u5206\u65f6\u95f4\u91cc\u90fd\u5728\u5feb\u901f\u5411\u897f\u79fb\u52a8\uff0c\u9000\u5316\u6210\u4e1c\u98ce\u6ce2\u540e\u7a7f\u8d8a\u4e86\u5411\u98ce\u7fa4\u5c9b\u3002'

def zng(paragraph):
    for sent in re.findall(u'[^!?。\.\!\?]+[!?。\.\!\?]?', paragraph, flags=re.U):
        yield sent

list(zng(paragraph))
```

Regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/eNFdqM/2

---

Answer (score 4):

Either of these open sources projects should be useful afaik:

- HanLP https://github.com/hankcs/HanLP
- FudanNLP https://github.com/FudanNLP/fnlp

Answer (score 2):

For unsegmented text, using the Stanford libraries, you probably want to use their Chinese CoreNLP.  This isn't as well documented as the base corenlp, but it will work for your task.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#languages
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

You will want the segmenter and the sentence splitter.  "segment, ssplit"  The others are not relevant.

Alternatively, you can use the WordToSentenceSplitter class in edu.stanford.nlp.process.WordToSentenceSplitter directly.  If you do that, you can look at how it is used in WordsToSentencesAnnotator.