# How to split a Chinese paragraph into sentences in Python?

Tags: python, chinese-locale

Since Chinese is different from English, so how we can split a Chinese paragraph into sentences (in Python)? A Chinese paragraph sample is given as

> 我是中文段落，如何为我分句呢？我的宗旨是“先谷歌搜索，再来问问题”，我已经搜索了，但是没找到好的答案。

To my best knowledge,

```
from nltk import tokenize
tokenize.sent_tokenize(paragraph, "chinese")
```

does not work because `tokenize.sent_tokenize()` doesn't support Chinese.

All the methods I found through Google search rely on Regular Expression (such as

```
re.split('(。|！|\!|\.|？|\?)', paragraph_variable)
```

). Those method are not complete enough. It seems that there is no a single regular expression pattern could be employed to split a Chinese paragraph into sentences correctly. I guess there should be some learned patterns to accomplish this task. But, I can't find them.

Comment: What about converting to English and then do it ?

Comment: Can you post more info on chinese paragraphs? How can they be detected? Are there always special signs?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441191/splitting-chinese-document-into-sentences

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, that's a possibility. But, the mapping between Chinese punctuation marks and English ones seems to be another problem.

Comment: I am not sure about the nature of the project, but if you are not doingthis  for educational purposes that I suggest but a Google translator API which will help you to convert this..then apply python to break to sentences